# What is the role of "ON [PRIMARY]" and "WITH" statement in creating tables and constrains in SQL Serer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's the difference between these two way of making a table and constrains?

1.

```
CREATE TABLE [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [Varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] DESC ) WITH ( IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE ([Name]) WITH ( IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON) 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2. 

```
CREATE TABLE [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Name] [Varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ([ID] DESC ),
UNIQUE ([Name])
WITH ( IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON) 
)
```

In the second form, the "CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable]" is omitted. Does it only affect automatic name selection of the constrain? Is the word "CONSTRAINT" neccessary?
Additionally, two "ON [PRIMARY]" are omitted. I think this changes where the tables and constrains are saved. What happens if you don't write any "ON..." or just write one of them?
Also in the later one, the "WITH" statement is only stated once. Does it apply for both constrains? Or each one of them has to have its own "WITH" statement?
Can you tell me all the practical differences of these two methode of creating tables?

Comment: These are two separate constructs so they are two separate questions.  I would advise you to just delete the question and look up the syntax in the SQL Server documentation.  It is all there.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your reply. I have been reading the documentation and auxiliary sources for many hours and although it was mentioned, was not clear to me. Yes, it's actually two question, but since they were minor issues, I thought better to ask them together. I hope I don't get much negatives.

Comment: Side note, I suggest you always explicitly name constraints regardless of the method you use to create them. Auto-generated constraint names will make subsequent schema modifications more difficult.

Comment: @Iraj . . . Two "little" totally unrelated questions are still *two* questions, which is why I voted to close this as "Needs more focus".

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a database by default it is created `PRIMARY` filegroup and all tables are stored in that filegroup.

The `PRIMARY KEY` is not added by default, you should explicitly set this constraint.

So, when you create a query like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar (50) NOT NULL
);
```

This is automatically converted behind in:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar (50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: Thank you. So, in the second block, the "ON [PRIMARY]" refers to the location of the whole table and doesn't have anything to do with the PRIMARY KEY? Do you also know how those "WITH" statements work?

Comment: @Iraj you have more information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-index-option-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you. I have read that. But I still don't know if a single "WITH" applies rules for all constrains or only a single constrain, immediately before it.

Comment: In your case is related to the index, because UNIQUE is creating an index and `WITH` command is setting up some special options.

Comment: So, it should be stated for each key individually. Right?

Comment: You should only if you want to apply some settings that are not default. For example IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF is the default, so if you want to change that you should add WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON).

Comment: I mean if I want to apply the same options for both constrains. It should be defined for each of them separately if I got it correctly.
And about "ON [PRIMARY]", do you think it is needed after defining each constrain? Or it is enough to define once for the whole table?

Comment: Yes for constraints and WITH. No for filegroup, you don't need to explicitly set ON [PRIMARY] if you have only one filegroup.